# How to Control Speed of Column-Updates in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, observable

I'm writing an application with `Java`, with some long running tasks. The status of each task consists of some values that are displayed in one row of a table  (one row for each task) with columns for each value of the status. Every-thing works fine but one little problem: The value for one of the columns changes very fast and frequently and is difficult to read, while the values for other columns change gracefully and are fine to read.

To implement this, I'm using a `TableModel` as an `Observer` and the tasks are `Observable` `Runnables`. Here's a short code depicting the layout of my program:

```java
public class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements Observer {

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        // Do some simple work then ...
        fireTableRowsUpdated(index, index);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return getRowTask(rowIndex).getState(columnIndex);
    }

    //
    // Other required methods ...
    //
}

//=============================================================//

public class RowTask extends Observable implements Runnable {

    public String[] state;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        initialize(state);
        while (!done) {
            // Do some fast work ...
            // Set new state values ...
            stateChanged();
        }
    }

    private void stateChanged() {
        // Notify observers that state has changed
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }

    public String getState(int index) {
        return state[index];
    }

    //
    // Other required methods ...
    //
}
```

To have a better understanding, an example scenario with this kind of problem would be a **download manager**. Each row shows info about each download like: file-name, progress-bar, speed, etc. Some columns are either fixed (like 'file-name'), or change gracefully (like 'progress-bar'), but some columns change very fast and frequent (like 'speed').

So what I need is a way to control the update speed of the frequently changing fields while not stopping the other graceful fields. What options do you suggest?

Comment: When I want to "slow" updates to the screen, I use a javax.swing.Timer. Basically, I restart the timer each time a request for change occurs and until it is triggered, I don't call the update method (from within the Timer's ActionListener). Now this will only work if there is a delay at some time long enough for the timer to trigger. You could use a counter, so that you only update on every n number of updates or a combination of the two...

Comment: The 'counter' suggestion was interesting and could solve the problem. I'll wait some more, for any other suggestions. Thanks.